# How is UIFocusMovementHint used?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tvos

When reading https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifocusmovementhint it is difficult for me to understand in what context the UIFocusMovementHint object is accessed and the variable of movementDirection can be read. Can anyone use this variable in a simple example?

Comment: Hey Bob ! Was I able to help with my answer? Please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many things using what is said in [this video at 16'29''](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc18/208?time=989) but I could not find anything really satisfying.

## EDIT

After asking to engineers at Apple during a Q&A, I realized I was doing something wrong. Here is a solution that works.

#### Use the transform properties

The class `UIFocusMovementHint` has several transform properties. Some are  `CATransform3D` which can be converted to affine transforms using `CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(_)`. Others are vectors and their properties used directly with `CGAffineTransform`.
Once you get a `CGAffineTransform` you can apply it to the [`transform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform) property of a view (you could otherwise use the layer).

In this example I'll use the [`translation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifocusmovementhint/3000776-translation) vector.

#### Container view

Rather than changing the `transform` property of the view you want to animate, a container view inside this view is needed. That's because **transforms affect the `frame` property** which makes the focus engine unable to properly handle the focus movement (that was my mistake).

So the container view should be added to the view to be animated and hold all the subviews that should take part of the hinting animation. The `transform` property of the container view could then be changed to reflect the hinting.

#### Example

A lot of words to explain something quite simple to write! Here it is:

```swift
override func didHintFocusMovement(_ hint: UIFocusMovementHint) {
  containerFocusView.transform = CGAffineTransform(
    translationX: hint.translation.dx, 
    y: hint.translation.dy
  )
}
```

#### Final note

I did not experiment with all the transform properties but I believe their usage should be quite similar.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. Your answer definitely helped me in the right direction. In my case I wanted to look at the UIFocusMovementHint's movementDirection (CGVector). By calculating the vector and determining which way focus is going I wanted to prevent focus from happening in some particular directions. This was done by analysing the direction in shouldUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext).